# ImportError: No module named google.appengine.ext.webapp.mail_handlers

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to get google app engine to work on my Raspberry Pi. I keep getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 26, in <module>
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.mail_handlers import InboundMailHandler
ImportError: No module named google.appengine.ext.webapp.mail_handlers
```

I downloaded google app engine and then ran these commands:

```
unzip google_appengine_1.9.40.zip 

export PATH=$PATH:/home/pi/google_appengine/
```

Comment: GAE is running on Google's cloud infra, I doubt you can get it to work on a Pi. What are you trying to achieve? How are you trying to use that GAE SDK you downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

The most trivial solution for such errors is to `import` the required package into you project directory. but to be honest it is not the best way to resolve this one. you may use `Google App Engine SDK` which will take care of all that headache, or there are another way you can follow:

1. Create a folder into your project directory and call it `lib`
2. Add all required packages into this folder.
3. Create a `.py` file and name it `appengine_config.py`
4. Add the below code snippets into this file:

   `import sys`

   `import os.path`

   `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'lib'))`

`appengine_config.py` gets loaded every time a new instance is started, and should take care of your modules importing.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're trying to directly execute your `main.py` as a standalone application, which is not how GAE app code works.

You're supposed to get the development server (from the SDK you downloaded) to execute your app code on your development machine (on GAE it's the GAE infra doing that). See [Using the Local Development Server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-local-server).