# importing google.cloud.datastore not working

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am working in pycharm(in windows) environment.

I am building a website to send query to datastore and display values. I also have data under `kind="SpecialTest"` that is automatically saved through ***Node.js***. Now I wanted to Query the data from Python.

I installed `google-cloud-datastore` from command line.

But I can't establish connection to datastore.

My code:

```
from google.cloud import datastore
cli=datastore.Client(project="My_project_I")
query4= cli.query(kind="SpecialTest").order('Published_at')
print query4
```

My result:

```
Internal Server Error

The server has either erred or is incapable of performing the requested operation.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1272, in default_dispatcher
    self.handlers[handler] = handler = import_string(handler)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1850, in import_string
    return getattr(__import__(module, None, None, [obj]), obj)
  File "C:\Users\Harry\workspace\www\app\account.py", line 11, in <module>
    from google.cloud import datastore
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\datastore\__init__.py", line 60, in <module>
    from google.cloud.datastore.batch import Batch
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\datastore\batch.py", line 24, in <module>
    from google.cloud.datastore import helpers
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\datastore\helpers.py", line 23, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import struct_pb2
ImportStringError: import_string() failed for 'app.account.UserAccount'. Possible reasons are:

- missing __init__.py in a package;
- package or module path not included in sys.path;
- duplicated package or module name taking precedence in sys.path;
- missing module, class, function or variable;

Original exception:

ImportError: No module named protobuf

Debugged import:

- 'app' found in 'C:\\Users\\Harry\\workspace\\www\\app\\__init__.pyc'.
- 'app.account' not found.
```

Comment: Is this python code part of a GAE app? Or just a regular python script running on your computer?

Comment: @DanCornilescu No ,i just specified the lines that has error. Now I Updated my whole code above. I'm testing it locally.

Comment: I reverted your edit, minimum code is better (as long as it covers the essentials): http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. I wasn't asking for more code, I was asking in which environment it runs - GAE apps and standalone scripts are different. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39260257/importerror-no-module-named-google-appengine-ext-webapp-mail-handlers/39282108#39282108

Comment: Never mind - the traceback (if I read it correctly) indicates a GAE app.

Comment: Yes ,Im working on website deployed on google-app-engine..

Comment: Was facing same issue some time ago have written answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38680593/importerror-no-module-named-google-protobuf/47904556#47904556. See if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datastore client library is not supplied by GAE, you need to [install/vendor it](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_third-party_library) into your application (different method than for a standalone script).

Alternatively you can use the GAE-specific datastore library - it's actually recommended as it offers some advantages over the general purpose one. From [Google App Engine Standard Environment Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#google_app_engine_standard_environment_client_libraries):

> Integrate Cloud Datastore with your App Engine Standard Environment
>   applications by using the App Engine client libraries.
>
> ...
>
> Python    [Google Datastore NDB Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/)
>
> **Note:** For App Engine applications that are written in Python, the Google Datastore DB Client Library is no longer recommended; use the
>   Google Datastore NDB Client Library instead.